# How do set up a Docker container with the 'tiredofit/freepbx' image to establish a WebSocket connection using SIP.js?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, freepbx, sip.js

**I have already set up my FreePBX application and tested it with Linphone. Now, I need to configure SIP.js to enable WebSocket connections. How can I do this?"**

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '2'
services:
  freepbx-app:
    container_name: freepbx-app
    image: tiredofit/freepbx
    ports:
      - 8010:80                     
      - 5060:5060/udp               
      - 5060:5060/tcp
      - 5160:5160/udp             
      - 5160:5160/tcp
      - 18000-18100:18000-18100/udp   
      - 4445:4445                 
      - 4080:443                
    volumes:
      - ./certs:/certs
      - ./data:/data
      - ./logs:/var/log
      - ./data/www:/var/www/html
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=pbx.co.in
      - VIRTUAL_NETWORK=nginx-proxy
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=8010
      - ZABBIX_HOSTNAME=freepbx-app
      - RTP_START=18000
      - RTP_FINISH=18100
      - DB_EMBEDDED=FALSE
      - DB_HOST=freepbx-db
      - DB_PORT=3306
      - DB_NAME=asterisk
      - DB_USER=asterisk
      - DB_PASS=asteriskpass
      - TLS_CERT=cert.pem
      - TLS_KEY=key.pem
    restart: always
    networks:
      - proxy-tier
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    privileged: true
  freepbx-db:
    container_name: freepbx-db
    image: tiredofit/mariadb
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./db:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=asterisk
      - MYSQL_USER=asterisk
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=asteriskpass
    networks:
      - proxy-tier

  freepbx-db-backup:
    container_name: freepbx-db-backup
    image: tiredofit/db-backup
    links:
      - freepbx-db
    volumes:
      - ./dbbackup:/backup
    environment:
      - ZABBIX_HOSTNAME=freepbx-db-backup
      - DB_HOST=freepbx-db
      - DB_TYPE=mariadb
      - DB_NAME=asterisk
      - DB_USER=asterisk
      - DB_PASS=asteriskpass
      - DB_DUMP_FREQ=1440
      - DB_DUMP_BEGIN=0000
      - DB_CLEANUP_TIME=8640
      - COMPRESSION=BZ
      - MD5=TRUE
    networks:
      - proxy-tier
    restart: always

networks:
  proxy-tier:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

I need to establish a WebSocket connection on FreePBX and configure it for use with SIP.js. Any help or solutions would be greatly helpful.